# While returning from onchange, Error: [_.sprintf] expecting number but found string

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have defined a onchange and returned the calculated age from give date of birth(dob)

```python
def onchange_getage_id(self, cr, uid, ids, dob, context=None):

    if dob:
        current_age = datetime.now().year - parser.parse(dob).year
        print current_age
        return {'value':{'age':current_age}}
    else:
        return {'value':{'age':' '}}
```

I have declared that age field has integer like this.

```python
'age' : fields.integer('Age'),
```

While entering dob it returns the age, but when we remove and give nothing in field it return with

```python
Error: [_.sprintf] expecting number but found string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!

If you have declared the field has integer you must have to return the dictionary value has integer.

I have returned it has space (`return {'value':{'age':' '}}`) that means string. This is the reason for error.

So did the following change in return value in else part.

```python
else
    return {'value':{'age':0}}
```